# Sign VBA (Macro's inside doc and/or docx) with Azure Key Vault (HSM)

Tags: code-signing, azure-keyvault

We have a new Code Sign certificate. This time it is an EV Code Sign certificate from GlobalSign. The certificate is now only available in Azure Key Vault as RSA-HSM.

I did manage to sign dll's and executables using AzureSignTool where I also asked [this question](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool/issues/126)

Todo:

- Use AzureSignTool inside Installshield professional, which is sadly not possible
- <strike>Use AzureSignTool inside Wix toolset</strike>

This question:

- Sign VBA (Macro's inside doc and/or docx)

After reading into what VBA signing is, I figured out that Signing a VBA file is in fact done by SignedCms. Looking at [the source from EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/96a7ac124515c41ce6336a64ed377549300d440a/src/EPPlus/Vba/ExcelVBASignature.cs#L263) I found that it is doing it that way.

Except that we do not have a private key directly, the azure key vault has. A piece of code can obtain it when it has access to the key vault, but only the RSA private key.

Perhaps this issue is related?
[dotnet/runtime#24707](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24707)

Which is implemented into .net core 3.0 and newer
[dotnet/corefx#29219](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/29219)

Comment: Not related to VBA Installshield premier version has build events, to be specific Precompilation event, where AzureSignTool can be called. And Wix can call AzureSignTool for SignCab and SignMSI without issues.

Now i'm still stuck with VBA... can it be i'm the only one with this problem!?

Comment: Hi @rfcdejong did you manage to solve the issue? Do you have any advice?

Comment: I didn't try it anymore as we just use a normal code sign certificate to sign with the normal sign tool. No time to dig into this again, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do exactly this and it was more painful than I had expected. It turns out that Azure Key Vault is currently the only cloud KMS that can do it. This is because VBA Macro signing requires at least one signature that uses MD5 and the other KMS providers (i.e., AWS KMS and Google KMS) only support SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 signature schemes. Azure Key Vault can do it because it supports RSNULL which means you can hash the data and apply the ASN.1 encoding client-side (in your cryptographic service provider) before sending it to Azure for signing.

Long story short, you need to implement the CNG interface to create a KSP that does the client-side hashing, ASN.1 encoding (since it is an RSA signature), and then sends the result to Azure for signing while specifying RSNULL as the signature algorithm. Alternatively, you can use a third party solution that does all this for you. We use [this one](https://garantir.io/use-cases/code-signing/), although there may be others out there as well.

Comment: Sounds great, any more informatie about implementing the CNG interface?

For now we simply bought two certificates and use the non EV cert to sign VBA. We might drop the EV code sign in the future, because signing with non EV is good enough in all cases.

Comment: Developing a KSP is a pretty broad topic but I would say a good place to start is downloading the [developer kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30688). There should be a sample KSP in there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sign Office files with VBA macros using [Azure Sign Tool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) with an Azure HSM-backed code signing certificate.

Follow these steps:

1. Install the [Office Subject Interface Packages/SIPs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617) according to the included readme. It might appear a bit complicated/cumbersome. Be sure to read it carefully.

   - SIPs *are a way to extend the types of files that Authenticode can understand how to sign and verify*. ([source](https://vcsjones.dev/subject-interface-packages/))
   - The Office SIPs are x86/32bit only. When using Windows' signing infrastructure from a 64bit process they won't be available. Thus, we need to make sure to execute AzureSignTool as 32bit.
2. Execute in a shell

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool.git
   cd AzureSignTool/src/AzureSignTool
   dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
   dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
   dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
   ```

   - Replace `-kvm` (`-kvm|--azure-key-vault-managed-identity UseManagedIdentity`)  with `-kvi <clientid> -kvs <clientsecret> -kvt <tenantid>` if you want to authenticate with a service principal and a corresponding client secret
   - It is actually required to run the same command 3x, to first create a legacy signature, then an agile signature, then a V3 signature. See readme of Office SIPs.

   This should output somehting like

   ```
   info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
         => File: D:\signtest.xlsm
      Signing file.
   info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
         => File: D:\signtest.xlsm
      Signing completed successfully.
   info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
         Successful operations: 1
   info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
         Failed operations: 0
   ```
3. Verify everything worked: `signtool verify /pa D:\signtest.xlsm`

   ```
   File: D:\signtest.xlsm
   Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
   ========================================
   0      sha256     RFC3161

   Successfully verified: D:\signtest.xlsm
   ```