# SignTool: can't sign XLSM (DOCM)

Tags: vba, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool, xlsm

I have a litte problem with Microsoft [SignTool.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe).
I have installed Windows 10 SDKs and
[Office SIPs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617) to support `macro enabled documents`. Then I followed `readme` to activate `dlls` and made all the changes, including:

1. Installed - Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Libraries
2. Set path to VBE7.DLL

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VBA]` 
`"Vbe71DllPath"="C:\Workspace\Signing\vbe7.dll"`

3. Registered `MSOSIPX.DLL` with `REGSVR32`
4. I have also created `wintrust.dll.ini` and added:

[1] 
DLL=<C:\Workspace\Signing\msosipx.dll>
GUID={6E64D5BD-CEB0-4B66-B4A0-15AC71775C48}
CryptSIPDllCreateIndirectData=_VBASipCreateIndirectData@12
CryptSIPDllGetSignedDataMsg=_VBASipGetSignedDataMsg@20
CryptSIPDllIsMyFileType2=_VBASipIsMyTypeOfFileName@8
CryptSIPDllPutSignedDataMsg=_VBASipPutSignedDataMsg@20
CryptSIPDllRemoveSignedDataMsg=_VBASipRemoveSignedDataMsg@8
CryptSIPDllVerifyIndirectData=_VBASipVerifyIndirectData@8

5. I'm using:

   `signtool sign /debug /n "Cert" /fd SHA256 test.xlsm`
   and the following happens:

**SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.

SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: test.xlsm

Number of files successfully Signed: 0

Number of warnings: 0

Number of errors: 1**

---

Little note at the end:

With **test.exe** it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using `regsvr32.exe` via `powershell` instead of `cmd`.

**Important note!** I'm calling `regsvr32.exe` on `msosipx.dll` in my working folder `C:\Workspace\Signing`.

P.S. I don't really understand why it's working.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this has been answered, but adding my input for anyone else coming across this.

I don't think you don't need the angle brackets for the path to the SIP module. As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Keys_(properties)) the syntax is key = value. So I would use:

```
[1]
DLL=C:\Workspace\Signing\msosipx.dll
```

Also make sure you are using the 32-bit version of signtool from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86"`. Using the 64-bit version I received the same error as you. But following the examples in the bundled `offsign.bat` and using the right version made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized` even after I registered the dlls.

I then noticed that I had ran `regsvr32` from an unelevated cmd (I have UAC active on my dev machine).

Even though it reported success, when I re-ran:

```
regsvr32 msosip.dll
regsvr32 msosipx.dll
```

from an Admin cmd, *and* made sure that I was using the x86 version of signtool, the signing of my `xlam` file was then successful:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v  /s My /n "Martin-Self-Office1" /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td SHA256 ".\f\Test-1-Addin.xlam"
...
Successfully signed: .\f\Test-1-Addin.xlam

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since June 1, 2023 all new code signing certificates (including OV) need to be stored using HSMs [[0](https://github.com/cabforum/code-signing/blob/main/docs/CSBR.md)] [[1](https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/new-private-key-storage-requirement-for-standard-code-signing-certificates-november-2022)]. Microsoft's SignTool can not be used with Cloud-based HSMs (like Azure Key Vault's Premium SKU), which are a popular option to satisfy the HSM requirement. If you come accross this question after 2023-06-01, an alternative for you that supports singing `xlsm` with Cloud-based HSM certificates is using [AzureSignTool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool). I added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78192171/1200847) which details how this process works:

> It is possible to sign Office files with VBA macros using [Azure Sign Tool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) with an Azure HSM-backed code signing certificate.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Install the [Office Subject Interface Packages/SIPs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617) according to the included readme. It might appear a bit complicated/cumbersome. Be sure to read it carefully.
>
>    - SIPs *are a way to extend the types of files that Authenticode can understand how to sign and verify*. ([source](https://vcsjones.dev/subject-interface-packages/))
>    - The Office SIPs are x86/32bit only. When using Windows' signing infrastructure from a 64bit process they won't be available. Thus, we need to make sure to execute AzureSignTool as 32bit.
> 2. Execute in a shell
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool.git
>    cd AzureSignTool/src/AzureSignTool
>    dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
>    dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
>    dotnet run sign "D:\signtest.xlsm" -kvm -kvu https://contoso-codesigning.vault.azure.net/ -kvc contoso-codesigning-ov -tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com/ -r win-x86
>    ```
>
>    - Replace `-kvm` (`-kvm|--azure-key-vault-managed-identity UseManagedIdentity`)  with `-kvi <clientid> -kvs <clientsecret> -kvt <tenantid>` if you want to authenticate with a service principal and a corresponding client secret
>    - It is actually required to run the same command 3x, to first create a legacy signature, then an agile signature, then a V3 signature. See readme of Office SIPs.
>
>    This should output somehting like
>
>    ```
>    info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
>          => File: D:\signtest.xlsm
>       Signing file.
>    info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
>          => File: D:\signtest.xlsm
>       Signing completed successfully.
>    info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
>          Successful operations: 1
>    info: AzureSignTool.SignCommand[0]
>          Failed operations: 0
>    ```
> 3. Verify everything worked: `signtool verify /pa D:\signtest.xlsm`
>
>    ```
>    File: D:\signtest.xlsm
>    Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
>    ========================================
>    0      sha256     RFC3161
>
>    Successfully verified: D:\signtest.xlsm
>    ```